# View with dynamic dataframe-number

Tags: r, user-interface

This code below is working fine to show the [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) with `View()`. Only want to change the appearance in [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) from `get(df[nr]))` to: `df1` (see picture).
e.g. df1 is a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe).

```
View(get(df[nr]))
```

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `View` there is a `title` argument that can be used here. Try :

```
View(get(df[nr]), df[nr])
```